# Using global dictionary inside flask route creates local reference for some reason

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Im trying to make a simple WebUI for raspberry pi project
I have a global dictionary which contains current states and im trying to update it using javascript in html and a route in flask, but for some reason it creates a local version of same variable which works as intended inside the route function but doesn't update the global one for some reason

I have shortened total code but its enough to understand what im trying to do

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request
import multiprocessing

states = {'light1': False, 'light2': False, 'light3': False, 'pump': False, 'detect1': False, 'detect2': False}

app = Flask(__name__)

def reverse(key:str) -> bool:
    states[key] = not states[key]
    return states

def run_server():
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')

@app.route('/update_states', methods=['POST'])
def update_states():
    # this code accepts json from html
    # and request converts it to dictionary in format of {'updated_state': string}
    # and then returns json converted from dictionary back to html
    
    # exactly here problem appears
    # global states dictionary for some reason only updates locally inside function
    # and not globally
    data = request.get_json()
    key = data['updated_state']
    new_states = reverse(key)
    states.update(new_states)
    return json.dumps(states)

# starting server on new thread because i need to execute code after starting server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_server)
    p.start()
```

Javascript code for the update_states function (Im new to javascript so code isn't great

```js
            $(function() {

                var xhr_states = new XMLHttpRequest();

                var light1 = document.getElementById('light1');
                var light2 = document.getElementById('light2');
                var light3 = document.getElementById('light3');
                var pump = document.getElementById('pump');
                var detect1 = document.getElementById('detect1');
                var detect2 = document.getElementById('detect2');
                var resp;

                setInterval(function() {

                    xhr_states.open('POST', '/update_states', true);

                    light1.onclick = function() {
                        resp = 'light1'
                    };

                    light2.onclick = function() {
                        resp = 'light2'
                    };

                    light3.onclick = function() {
                        resp = 'light3'
                    };

                    pump.onclick = function() {
                        resp = 'pump'
                    };

                    detect1.onclick = function() {
                        resp = 'detect1'
                    };

                    detect2.onclick = function() {
                        resp = 'detect2'
                    };
                    var sent = {
                        'updated_state': resp
                    }
                    if (resp != undefined){
                        xhr_states.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')

                        xhr_states.send(JSON.stringify(sent)); // (1)
                        resp = undefined
                    }
                    xhr_states.onreadystatechange = function() { // (3)
                    if (xhr_states.readyState != 4) return;
                        
                    if (xhr_states.status != 200) {
                        alert(xhr_states.status + ': ' + xhr_states.statusText);
                    } 
                    else {
                        var json = JSON.parse(xhr_states.responseText)
                        console.log(json)

                        if (json.light1) {
                            light1.className = 'btn btn-success';
                        }
                        else if (json.light1 == false) {
                            light1.className = 'btn btn-secondary';
                        }
                        if (json.light2) {
                            light2.className = 'btn btn-success';
                        }
                        else if (json.light2 == false) {
                            light2.className = 'btn btn-secondary';
                        }
                        if (json.light2) {
                            light2.className = 'btn btn-success';
                        }
                        else if (json.light2 == false) {
                            light2.className = 'btn btn-secondary';
                        }
                        if (json.light3) {
                            light3.className = 'btn btn-success';
                        }
                        else if (json.light3 == false) {
                            light3.className = 'btn btn-secondary';
                        }
                        if (json.pump) {
                            pump.className = 'btn btn-success';
                        }
                        else if (json.pump == false) {
                            pump.className = 'btn btn-secondary';
                        }
                        if (json.detect1) {
                            detect1.className = 'btn btn-success';
                        }
                        else if (json.detect1 == false) {
                            detect1.className = 'btn btn-secondary';
                        }
                        if (json.detect2) {
                            detect2.className = 'btn btn-success';
                        }
                        else if (json.detect2 == false) {
                            detect1.className = 'btn btn-secondary';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, 1000);
            });
```

I was trying to specify to use global variable but its not helping